# HTML5 <section> element doesn't accept a negative margin-top in Firefox 3.6.x

Tags: css, firefox, html

I'm trying to use a negative top margin on a  element and it is not working in Firefox. Chrome and IE (using HTML5-shiv) are rendering it properly. I have given the HTML5 elements (including  a display: block).

Thoughts? CSS if you need it:

```
aside, article, section { display: block; }


section#banner {
background: url(images/banner.png) no-repeat 3px 3px;
border: #CCD1DB 1px solid;
-moz-border-radius: 10px; /* FF1+ */
-webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Saf3+, Chrome */
border-radius: 10px; /* Opera 10.5, IE 9 */
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #E0E3E9; /* FF3.5+ */
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #E0E3E9; /* Saf3.0+, Chrome */
box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #E0E3E9; /* Opera 10.5, IE 9.0 */
display: block;
height: 350px;
margin: -50px auto 0;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 3px;
position: relative;
width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `section` for styling, use div instead.

Comment: @rebus: you have a point, a section is for something akin to a chapter, not a division of a page: http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100304/Overview.html#the-section-element

Comment: Don't use section to style elements. It is not made for that and it won't work.

Answer (score 3):

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-section-element

> The section element is not a generic
>   container element. When an element is
>   needed for styling purposes or as a
>   convenience for scripting, authors are
>   encouraged to use the div element
>   instead. A general rule is that the
>   section element is appropriate only if
>   the element's contents would be listed
>   explicitly in the document's outline.

More resources:
http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/

Comment: thanks. kind of ridiculous, imo...but i appreciate the reference.

Comment: This doesn't mean you can't, just that you shouldn't.

Comment: unfortunately, changing it to a <div> didn't fix the issue. :(

Comment: CSS is sometimes tricky to debug, there could be other styles applied to `#banner` element that together cause this behaviour. Try checking with Firebug https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/

Comment: Yeah, I've checked with firebug and it shows that the negative margin exists, but the content isn't moving up.